# Amplify range of selection into error bar series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using a custom way to show a tooltip in Highchart and everything is working well when I choose series of type: spline.. but when I tried to do the same for series of `type: "error bar"` it is hard to choose the line. Is there some way to increment of the range of selection for this kind of series?

This piece of code represent how the code is working to show the tooltip.
I suppose that I should add some code to hover event?

```
events : {
    click : function(evt) {
        this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
    },
    mouseOut : function() {
        this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
    }                       
}
```

### Full Code

```js
x = null;

$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C',
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        events: {
          click: function(evt) {
            this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
          },
          mouseOut: function() {
            this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'Temperature error',
      type: 'errorbar',
      data: [
        [6, 8], [5.9, 7.6], [9.4, 10.4], [14.1, 15.9], [18.0, 20.1], [21.0, 24.0],
        [23.2, 25.3], [26.1, 27.8], [23.2, 23.9], [18.0, 21.1], [12.9, 14.0]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that you can make some small workaround of your issue. You may add new errorbar series with bigger lineWidth and transparent color. It should give you a chance to display the tooltip for your errorbars when you are not clicking directly on it. Here you can find an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4qLgu8so/1/

Comment: hi @GrzegorzBlachliński, your solution is right for me. please pos it as an answer :)

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. :) I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some small workaround of your issue. You can add new errorbar series with bigger lineWidth and transparent color.

```
{
      name: 'Temperature error',
      type: 'errorbar',
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      lineWidth: 20,
      data: [
        [6, 8],
        [5.9, 7.6],
        [9.4, 10.4],
        [14.1, 15.9],
        [18.0, 20.1],
        [21.0, 24.0],
        [23.2, 25.3],
        [26.1, 27.8],
        [23.2, 23.9],
        [18.0, 21.1],
        [12.9, 14.0]
      ]
    }
```

It should give you a chance to display the tooltip for your errorbars when you are not clicking directly on it.

Here you can find an example how it can work:  http://jsfiddle.net/4qLgu8so/1/

Kind regards,